# IBDesignable UILabel setting text to NSLocalizedString in drawRect or willMoveToSuperview crashes Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ibdesignable

I am trying to retroactively localize an app by subclassing an `IBDesignable` to have a property like so:

```
@property IBInspectable NSString *localizedKey;
```

Then I thought I could easily override the proper function in the `UILabel`'s lifecycle to do this:

```
if (self.localizedKey) self.text = NSLocalizedString(self.localizedKey, nil);
```

Here's an example of what I tried to do:

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    NSLog(@"roundedlabel");
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:borderWidth];
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[borderColor CGColor]];
    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

- (void) willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview {
    [super willMoveToSuperview:newSuperview];
    NSLog(@"roundedlabel");
    if (self.localizedKey) self.text = NSLocalizedString(self.localizedKey, nil);
}
```

I also tried moving the `if (self.localizedKey)` to various locations in `drawRect`.

My plan was to then set up the `Localizable.strings` file manually with known `localizedKey`s assigned working through the `XIB` files. However, I am finding two things.

1. It seems as though the normal methods called in the life cycle
   of a view are not being called for my IBDesignable UILabel subclass.
   I have entered log statements into `drawRect` and
   `willMoveToSuperview`, and these log statements never print out.
2. XCode almost always crashes & immediately closes when I try to open
   a xib in Interface Builder that contains this subclassed label (so no error messages).

At run time, when I see a view that involves an affected xib, I don't see any sign of the localized string AND I don't see '`roundedlabel`' printed anywhere in my log.

What's going on? In particular:

**(1) How come these functions don't run at all for my subclassed IBDesignable UILabel subclass?
(2) Is there a way to do what I want to do?**

Comment: have you already subclassed `UILabel` or you've done it just for the designable? is there a reason you chose designable as the approach to take?

Comment: @Wain I am seeking to retroactively localize many xibs where the copy & layout are frequently changed. For this reason, I don't want to generate many separately localized xib files (too difficult to maintain), and I want to avoid migrating all the text assignments to .m files rather than xibs.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create an extension on `UILabel` and use runtime key values in the storyboard / XIB to set the localisation keys.

```
extension UILabel {
    func setHBLocalisationKey(key: String) {
        self.text = ...
     }
}
```

or

```
@implementation UILabel (HBLocalisation)

    - (void)setHBLocalisationKey:(NSString *)key {
        self.text = NSLocalizedString(key, nil);
    }

@end
```

This will now work on any label without requiring a custom subclass and it won't tamper with the Xcode UI which seems to be causing some issues with your current approach.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure how your recommendation fully translates over to my approach in Objective C. I don't see how doing this as a class extension rather than as a subclass changes the issue. In particular, ultimately I need the function to run at run time. My problem is that I can't seem to find a function that is running at runtime.

Comment: sorry, too used to writing in swift now :( if you're using IBDesignable then it's static anyway. you could use a category in the same way as the extension, it'll work in exactly the same way. it's a different approach, it doesn't translate to your approach, just to your requirement

Comment: I'm all for it, but part of my question is why the methods don't seem to get executed? What would I call the category and how would I set it?

Comment: i've added the category, the category method is executed by setting the key value pair `HBLocalisationKey` : `XXX` the storyboard as described here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-interface_builder/Chapters/AddUserDefinedRuntimeAttributes.html

Comment: i don't know why your current approach isn't working, i don't know enough about it, but it's also more complex and has more requirements then my suggestion